# Database relationship between products, categories and companies

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm creating an EER Diagram with MySQL Workbench.

What is the best way to implement a relationship between products, categories and companies tables?

I was thinking in this relation, but is this the best way considering I want to allow custommers of a company to manage their own products/categories? Isn't this a problem if I want to list only the categories of a company?

[image]

The second relation I designed is this one:

[image]

Which one is a good relation for my purpose? Or should I use an another one that can make it easier to manage only the products of a company or only the categories -> products of an company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the second one if every company should be able to have its own categories. Think about it if you would not have a company_id in your category. Then you would not be able to assign a category to a company. Also please declare your foreign keys like "category_id" and not "id_category". First one is better readable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What you said about the second relationship makes sense. If you don't mind, I would like to know if there will be another suggestion before checking an answer as the better one.

Comment: Is this bad if I make a triple relationship? company->category, company->product and category->product?

Comment: Your suggestion "company->product" is redundant because you can get the information which product belongs to which company over your categories-relation. When modelling databases you always try to prevent redundancies.